# AWS Device farm - iOS - app.launchEnviorment issues

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, aws-device-farm

The issue is app.launchEnvoirnment["key"] = "value" is being ignored on AWS, but runs fine on Circle CI and locally.

Comment: If you found the answer useful please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I work for the AWS Device farm team.

Unfortunately, this is not currently supported on AWS Device Farm. I have made a note of this as it is an item which is our current backlog.

I would suggest checking the AWS forums for update on this.